# Find and post-mortem details of a problematic git merge commit

Tags: git, merge

There was a new programmer who put in a merge commit which messed a lot of things up, but I'm honestly not exactly sure what he did, and I'm wanting to look at the merge commit both to (a) find out what happened, (b) find out if there were any other problems (or similar commits) and (c) help him not to make the same mistake as before.

Basically New Programmer (NP) was working in branch A.  Experienced Programmer (EP) was working in branch B.  Line 200 of file Q had been modified by Long-Gone Programmer (LGP) in 2018.  EP made a modification of Line 200 of file Q in November 2019 in branch B, commit abc123.  NP merged branch B into branch A in December 2019.

After this merge, branch A *DOES NOT* reflect commit abc123 *AT ALL*.  A "git blame" still shows that the line was last modified by LGP in 2018.  It does not reflect either the change by EP nor the reversion of this by the merge by NP.  A "git show" of the merge commit just says that it merged.  a "git diff-tree -cc" of the merge commit doesn't show anything at all, just the commit number.

Anyway, does anyone (a) know what could have happened, (b) know how to convince git to give me more information, (c) search for this problem in the past, or (d) help prevent the problem in the future?

Comment: Unfortunately, there just isn't enough information there to know *how* a commit got into a given state -- someone can always manually munge a tree to reflect any manner of possible states. It's a bit like asking "what could someone do wrong in their IDE to delete function-X?", when we don't know which editor they're using, which plugins they have, whether they used any refactoring modules, what precise procedure or steps they tried to follow, etc.

Comment: For all we can tell, maybe there was a `git checkout branchB -- filename` to try to force a merge conflict to be resolved in the new working tree's failure; we just don't have any way of knowing. Now, if you can specify a [mre] for an exact and precise procedure to us, and ask "why does following steps A through C result in state D instead of expected state E?", *that* is a question that's amenable to a concrete answer without speculation involved.

Comment: Except that this is clearly something weird, because the blame erased history.  It doesn't show that NP made a modification to the commit, it shows that EP *never changed* it.  I would expect that this would have fewer possible causes.

Comment: "Erased history" means something very specific in the git world, and you can prevent it from happening if you turn off force-push operations. If force-push is allowed, it's *normal* for people to be able to erase history.

Comment: My main question is to get git to show me what happened.  When I do a "git show" on the commit, it shows me no information.  Obviously there is information there because it knows to remove the file on that commit.  How can I get access to this information?  Note that my question is multipart, because I recognize that not everything may be answerable.  However, as is the point of the board, people with more experience than me may have seen similar situations which might help me find the solution.

Comment: Anyhow -- if you open up the tree in `tig`, there should be two lines coming out from the merge commit, one to each branch. If it's really the original branches there (commitishes match) and in one of those `git blame` shows the change, then we don't have rewritten history in the sense above.

Comment: Did you actually read the question?  This isn't about force pushing, this is about an actual merge that erased history.  I can go into my tree, I can follow it, I can see the original commit, I can see the merge, and I can see that *after* the merge it pretends like the original commit never happened, and the git blame shows the original code/modification time before any of this happened.

Comment: If it's an actual merge, and the `Merge:` line in `git show` of the merge commit shows both inputs, history was not erased, *period*. Not in the sense of what "erased history" means in git. If you mean that `git blame` no longer shows something, that's different from history being erased.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204496/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-johnnyb).

Answer (score 1):

After discussions with Charles Duffy, I developed a command line tool to do what I am looking for.  The code (mergeexamine.sh) is below:

```
$!/bin/sh

MERGECOMMIT=$1

COMMITA=`git show $MERGECOMMIT|grep Merge:|head -n 1|cut -d' ' -f2`
COMMITB=`git show $MERGECOMMIT|grep Merge:|head -n 1|cut -d' ' -f3`

DIFFA=`mktemp`
git diff ${MERGECOMMIT}^..${MERGECOMMIT} > $DIFFA

DIFFB=`mktemp`
git diff ${COMMITA}...${COMMITB} > $DIFFB

diff $DIFFA $DIFFB

rm $DIFFA $DIFFB
```

Therefore, to see the possible strange changes that occur within a merge, I can do "mergeexamine.sh COMMITNUMBER".  If it is a fairly straightforward merge, the results will look something like:

```
143c143
< index b46f8126..703c463e 100644
---
> index ff005c38..0df69834 100644
```

But, if there were a lot of differences that were incorporated in the merge, it will show what those are.

I am still unsure how to tell if some commit gets dropped in a merge.  This script, I believe, will show changes between an "expected" merge and the actual merge.  From that, you can manually suss out if something got dropped.  If anyone knows how to do this automatically, please add an additional answer.

Additionally, if anyone knows what sort of commit commands someone would have to be doing for a change to not show up in blame, that would be helpful.